# One class for multiple selectors in CSS3

Tags: css

Im currently using the plugin [vertical timeline](https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html). This plugin happens to use CSS that affects my current base style sheet. Please correct my understanding if needed. I have the following block of CSS code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I wish for this to only affect the elements in `cd-container`. I would like to know if there's a simple way to do this versus the code below:

```
.cd-container html, .cd-container body, .cd-container div, .cd-container span, .cd-container applet, .cd-container  object, .cd-container  iframe, .cd-container 
h1, .cd-container  h2, .cd-container  h3, .cd-container  h4, .cd-container  h5, .cd-container  h6, .cd-container  p, .cd-container  blockquote, .cd-container  pre, .cd-container 
a, .cd-container  abbr, .cd-container  acronym, .cd-container  address, .cd-container  big, .cd-container  cite, .cd-container  code, .cd-container 
del, .cd-container  dfn, .cd-container  em, .cd-container  img, .cd-container  ins, .cd-container  kbd, .cd-container  q, .cd-container  s, .cd-container  samp, .cd-container 
small, .cd-container  strike, .cd-container  strong, .cd-container  sub, .cd-container  sup, .cd-container  tt, .cd-container  var, .cd-container 
b, .cd-container  u, .cd-container  i, .cd-container  center, .cd-container 
dl, .cd-container  dt, .cd-container  dd, .cd-container  ol, .cd-container  ul, .cd-container  li, .cd-container 
fieldset, .cd-container  form, .cd-container  label, .cd-container  legend, .cd-container 
table, .cd-container  caption, .cd-container  tbody, .cd-container  tfoot, .cd-container  thead, .cd-container  tr, .cd-container  th, .cd-container  td, .cd-container 
article, .cd-container  aside, .cd-container  canvas, .cd-container  details, .cd-container  embed, .cd-container  
figure, .cd-container  figcaption, .cd-container  footer, .cd-container  header, .cd-container  hgroup, .cd-container  
menu, .cd-container  nav, .cd-container  output, .cd-container  ruby, .cd-container  section, .cd-container  summary, .cd-container 
time, .cd-container  mark, .cd-container  audio, .cd-container  video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

The following is a snippet of my code for the timeline based on the [demo](https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html)

```
<div id="vertTimeline">
    <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                <img src="/Content/plugins/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
            </div>
            <!-- cd-timeline-img -->
            <div class="cd-timeline-content">
                <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
                <span class="cd-date">Jan 14</span>
            </div>
            <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
                <img src="/Content/plugins/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
            </div>
            <!-- cd-timeline-img -->
            <div class="cd-timeline-content">
                <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde?</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
                <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
            </div>
            <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
    </section>
    <!-- cd-timeline -->
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, unless  you want to look into *scoping*. This feels like an [**XY Problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to do? Because as far as I see, you might as well use the '*' to select all elements

Comment: Im using a plugin called [vertical timeline] https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html and the css that it comes with it breaking my default stylesheet because of scenarios like I mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried adding the offending stylesheet before your regular styles, the order matters for which styles take precedence.

Comment: Why not remove the CSS from the plugin's stylesheet or override it? It's expected that a third party feature such as this is going to make it's own decisions about layout. If you want more/less margin on an element, change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.cd-container * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

---

The `*` is the universal selector, which *should* select all descendant elements of `.cd-container`. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an extremely inefficient solution, not just because the `*` selector is inefficient by itself but because browsers read style rules right-to-left, meaning the browser is going to target every element on the page and see if any of these has an ancestor (not just a parent) which is `.cd-container`. For every element, the browser has to traverse up its ancestor tree all the way up to the `body` and `html` tags before it can give up and realize the styles don't apply.

Comment: @skyline3000 it is an inefficient solution, but sadly it is the only way to get done what he wants